# SAPUI5 JSON Model via REST API - Using DESTINATION in xs-app.json / BTP does not resolve Correctly

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-foundry

Creating a call to a REST API to load a JSON model to bind to the view/controller. Creating a freestyle Fiori App using the Managed App Router

1. In oninit function within the view controller, try to load a JSON Model to bind to view

e.g. (new JSONModel()).loadData("/Products");  NB: Full URL is = https://dummyjson.com/Products)

2. xs-app.json Entry as follows
   {
   "source": "^/Products",
   "destination": "APITEST",
   "authenticationType": "xsuaa",
   "csrfProtection": false
   },
3. APITEST Destination in BTP configured with no authentication and URL = https://dummyjson.com/
4. The HTML5 app is deployed to BTP Cloud Foundry

Get a 404 error when clicking on the app from the BTP Cockpit HTML5 app list.   However if I change step 1 to remove the prefix /Products to Products it resolves correctly. e.g.

(new JSONModel()).loadData("Products") is good.  But to further complicate matters, when I then deploy the app to the Build App launchpad, it stops working ! NB. I have tried both variations with the launchpad and it doesn't work either with the leading / or without.

Any pointers on how I may have configured the files incorrectly to get this to resolve.

In the case (without a launchpad) and using "Products" in the relative URL, the resolved URL when I look in the 'Network' via Developer Tools in Chrome includes the application name as part of the URL to access via the Destination Service

Answer (score 0):

Realised that you need to prefix the URL correctly when calling the loadData() method on the JSON model using the following utility

sap.ui.require.toUrl(appPath+"/Products").

var appId = this.getOwnerComponent().getManifestEntry(“/sap.app/id”);
var appPath = appId.replaceAll(“.”, “/”);

Taken from the following blog but using sap.ui.require.toUrl as getModulePath is now deprecated.

https://blogs.sap.com/2020/09/08/calling-external-api-in-custom-task-ui-of-workflow-in-cloud-foundry/